# bg image positioning in table header

Tags: css

How to achieve the following with css (background color with background image that overlaps header row):
[image]

This is the part of TH cell in the table.
TH line would be in color #0098da and at the end of TH cell would be image (the url of images is here http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/pg_arrow.png).

I have tried to position div with bg image in TH, but I had problems that image should overlap TH borders. And as a result I got the followign:

[image]

HTML:

```
    <table id="duration-of-refund" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <p>Purchases in Webshops</p>
                <div class="img-at">&nbsp;</div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <p>Currency conversion, Refund transfer</p>
                <div class="img-arrow">&nbsp;</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
    #duration-of-refund td {
     width: 400px;
 }
 #duration-of-refund th {
     font-size: 21px;
     color: white;
     text-align: left;
     height: 84px;
     max-height: 84px;
 }
 #duration-of-refund tr th:nth-child(1) {
     background-color: #0098da;
 }
 #duration-of-refund tr th:nth-child(2) {
     background-color: #1F5CA9;
 }
 #duration-of-refund tr th:nth-child(1) p, #duration-of-refund tr th:nth-child(2) p {
     width: 190px;
     float: left;
 }
 .img-at, .img-arrow {
     width: 83px;
     height: 84px;
     float: right;
     margin-right: 20px;
     position: relative;
     top: -20px;
 }
 .img-arrow {
     background-image: url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/pg_arrow.png);
 }
 .img-at {
     background-image: url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/pg_at.png);
 }
 #duration-of-refund tr td:nth-child(2) {
     background-color: #cceaf8;
 }
}
```

JSfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/rAVqx/

I think, that theres should be another way how to do this.

Please, give me some clues how to achieve this? I have also other TH cells with different images to be positioned in the same way.

Comment: Constructs like that usually work best if you set the cell spacing to 0.

Comment: Oh, and can I give you a friendly hint. When working with tables, you will usually get lots of snide remarks about how you should avoid those. In many cases, you can prevent that by not putting "some text here" in the source, but rather "some tabular data here". That will shut them up.

Answer (score 0):

try this
put image class tag in another div and apply styles as

```
 float:right;margin-right:90px
```

and for image position as absolute

```
 position: absolute;
```

your code is just modified

**HTML**

```
<table id="duration-of-refund" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <p>Purchases in Webshops</p>
                <div style="float:right;margin-right:90px;">
                <div class="img-at">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <p>Currency conversion, Refund transfer</p>
                <div style="float:right;margin-right:90px;">
                <div class="img-arrow">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
#duration-of-refund td {
     width: 400px;
 }
 #duration-of-refund th {
     font-size: 21px;
     color: white;
     text-align: left;
     height: 84px;
     max-height: 84px;
 }
 #duration-of-refund tr th:nth-child(1) {
     background-color: #0098da;
 }
 #duration-of-refund tr th:nth-child(2) {
     background-color: #1F5CA9;
 }
 #duration-of-refund tr th:nth-child(1) p, #duration-of-refund tr th:nth-child(2) p {
     width: 190px;
     float: left;
 }
 .img-at, .img-arrow {
     width: 83px;
     height: 84px;
     float: right;
     margin-right: 20px;
     position: absolute;
     top: -20px;
 }
 .img-arrow {
     background-image: url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/pg_arrow.png);
 }
 .img-at {
     background-image: url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/pg_at.png);
 }
 #duration-of-refund tr td:nth-child(2) {
     background-color: #cceaf8;
 }
}
```